# doctrine entity manager - unable to save data into DB if run through console application

Tags: php, batch-file, doctrine-orm, console-application, symfony-2.6

I am working on a batch process and it run via command line. In console application, I use `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')` to get access to doctrine ORM where as from any controller file `$emr = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` is being used. This second methos won't work for console/command line.

If I try to use any function(functions in controller) which `persists` or `save` data into the DB, it is giving error.

```
private function addActionForReject($docketNumber, $emr)
{
    $mAction = new Action();

    $date = new \DateTime();
    $mAction->setActionId(ConstantRest::NO_FURTHUR_REVIEW_ACTION_ID);
    .....
    $emr->persist($mAction );

    $emr->flush();
```

Thsi above function exits in a controller and In batch file I have created an instance of that. Using instance I called `addActionForReject` by passing `$emr` object that is `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')` in this case.

But this will giving error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function has() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\GR\
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.
php on line 288`

NOTE: I am able to fetch data from DB. issue is only when I try to save an object data.

Comment: It is because you actually calling a different controller method (addActionForReject is private so your command cannot be calling it).  And then the actual method being called is trying to access the non-existent container object.  This is a very common question.  Your best bet is to move the addActionForReject into it's own service and then share the service between the controller and the command.  Trying to call controller actions from commands seldom ends well.

Comment: @Cerad I tried to change it to `Public` from `private `. Still the error is same. I will try service approach now. Thanks.